# Add a list of IP as Source IP in Security Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

I have a list of IP addresses. I want to allow `tcp/22` traffic from them and block any other IP address. The list is long and contains about 50-60 IP addresses. How can I add this to a Security Group without manually adding them one by one.

Thankyou!

Solution:

I found a way using `aws` cli

For allowing SSH to a range of cidrs

```
bash# for ip in {csv_list_of_cidrs}
> do
> aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id <sg_ig_here> --protocol tcp --port 22 --cidr $ip
> done
```

eg:

```
for ip in {1.1.1.1/8,2.2.2.2/16,3.2.3.12/29}
do
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-xxxxxxxxx --protocol tcp --port 22 --cidr $ip
done
```

For solution using`boto3` refer to the answer below

Comment: Are those ips stored in a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a boto3 script that you could use:

```
    ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
    ec2_client.authorize_security_group_ingress(
        GroupId=group_id,
        IpPermissions=[
            {
                'IpProtocol': 'tcp',
                'FromPort': 22,
                'ToPort': 22,
                'IpRanges': [ip_list_here]
            }
        ])
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't see this documented elsewhere, so posting here for when I forget the answer again :-).  If it belongs on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com) let me know and I will start a question for it there.

It ***is*** possible to add multiple IP addresses to a single AWS security rule using the AWS console, but ***careful formatting of the input is required!***  For example, to add the following two addresses to a single rule,

```
49.234.87.61
122.212.240.26
```

I compose a single line in a text editor consisting of:

```
49.234.87.61/32, 122.212.240.26/32
```

I then paste the above line into my AWS console's address field and hit my keyboard's <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  Here is a picture of the result:

[image: AWS console snapshot]